# Filters on ActiveRecord collection without firing off additional sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I make a query like so in order to return an ActiveRecord collection of objects:

```
@animals = Animal.all
```

Then elsewhere in my code I grab records from that collection:

```
#fires off additional sql query but I do not want it to
@specific_animals = @animals.where(animal_type: 'mammal')

#fires off additional sql query but I do not want it to
@specific_animals = @animals.where(animal_type: 'bird')
```

I only want the first statement of `Animal.all` to fire off an sql query.  I would think that once you have the collection, there is no reason to query the database again for filters on that collection.

**Question:** How can I make it so that I can filter that ActiveRecord collection without making additional queries to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord queries translate to SQL statements, which are only useful when sent to a database. But you can just use Ruby array methods to filter.

```
@specific_animals = @animals.select { |a| a.animal_type == 'mammal' }
```

Note that you can no longer use this array with other ActiveRecord scopes or queries after using a Ruby array method, like `select`, `reject`, `sort`, etc.